# script pdf atom's pdf generation

Tags: pdf, markdown, atom-editor

Atom is great for generating a preview from a markdown file.  It also has a great package for generating a pdf.

My current process for generating a pdf of my README.md is the following:

1)   to open README.md in atom.
2)   Click the menu option: Packages-> Markdown to PDF -> Convert

I would like to be able to do something like the following:

```sh
$ atom README.md --markdown-to-pdf
```

In the past, I have used pandoc for a command line version of this, but I like the atom package's rendering better.

Is there a programmatic interface for atom?

Answer (score 0):

There is a Node module that converts Markdown files to PDFs named [markdown-pdf](https://github.com/alanshaw/markdown-pdf). You can use this module as alternative.

Install:

```
npm install -g markdown-pdf --ignore-scripts
```

Usage:

```
markdown-pdf [options] <markdown-file-path>
```

Also you can find more usage of it in [here](https://github.com/alanshaw/markdown-pdf#usage).

Comment: I think this could be a good option.  I awarded the bounty but when i run it, it just throws an error.  Is there a stable version that i should try?